grid fill not working on a vertices
hey all I just have a quick question that I wanted to ask , so basically I m creating a model which as it shown in the picture , I created a plane deleted 3 vertices kept one vertices, after that I followed the reference image and now after that selected all vertices and press F to fill , Also I wanted to sculpt the mesh but there is no vertices on the middle  so It has enough vertices , I Hope you get what I mean Because I m trying to sculpt the mesh so it fit the reference image Thanks In Advance 
blend :



Check that your loop has an even number of vertices round it or Grid fill won't work. You could also try temporarily disabling the mirror modifier although I'm not sure if that affects its operation.

Also make sure that the last two verts in the loop are actually joined by Merging by Distance or joining with F.

thank you for ur reply , the grid fill worked but its messed up actually is there  a way ? as it shown in the pic , blend file available

Unfortunately not. Any type of fill is going to have problems with an irregular object like that. You could try checking Simple Blending in the bottom-left settings menu directly after you've selected Grid Fill and play with the Span and Offset settings to try to improve the layout but you'll still have problems with a shape like that. The only other way is to chop it up by selecting opposing verts and using 'F' to connect them across the object a pair at a time, but that would be pretty tedious.
